# ANTLR4 Python failed to install and cannot establish a connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, apache-age

I am trying to install the requirements of Apache AGE Python driver. Whenever it comes to installing the antlr4-python3-runtime, it fails.

I install the packages through:

```bash
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This gets the following:

```bash
Collecting antlr4-python3-runtime==4.11.1
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce27dfd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce27df2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce27dee90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce27def50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce27df0d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8ce2818190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

- OS: Ubunutu 22.04
- Python version: 3.10.6

To reproduce:

```
# update and install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libpq-dev
# get apache age
git clone https://github.com/apache/age
# move to the drivers
cd age/drivers/python
# create virtual environment 
virtualenv venv
# active
source venv/bin/activate
# install
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

P.S When I have tried to download the package files from https://pypi.org/project/antlr4-python3-runtime/#files
it has been downloaded

Has anyone got a similar issue and/or a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can try manually installing the package:

1. If you haven't already downloaded the package:

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/64/c548678120cccf784f555972ed37cedcf4f026abeec30ab0340c3af4ea07/antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
```

2. Install the package:

```
pip install antlr4-python3-runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall `antlr`.
To uninstall:

```
pip uninstall antlr4-python3-runtime
```

To install:

```
pip install antlr4-python3-runtime==4.11.1
```

I am using antlr version 4.11.1, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

since the manual download method is not working for you, you can use the following command to install it from the downloaded file:

```
pip3 install path_to_downloaded_file/antlr4_python3_runtime-4.11.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try to install the `antlr4-python3-runtime 4.13.0` in other library.

in the case you already have installed the packages, so run the `pip install` directly in the file, like:

```
pip3 install antlr4.11.1.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to install a specific version of antlr4 preferably as the driver does not work with all versions, 4.9.2 or 4.11 should work depending on whether the repo was cloned or you installed AGE directly.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76102182/21315036).